# In SQL how can I use an index to speed up this database query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `album` (
  `album_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `artist_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `album_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `first_released` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`album_id`),
  KEY `artist_id` (`artist_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `artist` (
  `artist_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('Band','Person','Unknown','Combination') NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gender` enum('Male','Female') DEFAULT NULL,
  `founded` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`artist_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

My first query:

```
select ar.name, count(*)   
from artist ar 
join album al on ar.artist_id=al.artist_id   
group by ar.artist_id  
limit 10;
```

which produces a result set in 0.00 seconds.

I would like to order the results, so I add "order by 2 desc":

```
select ar.name, count(*)  
from artist ar  
join album al on ar.artist_id=al.artist_id  
group by ar.artist_id  
order by 2 desc  
limit 10;
```

but now the result set takes over 5 seconds, which is too slow.

Execution plan:
[image]

How can I add an index to speed up my new query?

Sample data: http://bit.ly/1k5ROrT

Comment: hi @davidjhp, i'm sorry but what `order by 2 desc` will do ?

Comment: This sorts the result set, by number of albums, in descending order.  It provides a list of artists that have the highest number of albums.

Comment: What does your execution plan look like?

Comment: @Hardy - You can order by column ordinal. This is widely discouraged as being prone to errors if you add additional columns in though. Adding a column alias and ordering by that would be preferable.

Comment: Try also a query just on Album table (Remove `name` from the select list, and the join) How much time?

Comment: @alroc, I added the execution plan.

Comment: @Itay Moav -Malimovka, 
select * from album where artist_id='500';
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should select and count with indexed column which will make better order by performance, then you can join artist name on the filtered result to complete your data.  Something will like.

```
SELECT ar2.name, t.c
FROM
(
  SELECT ar.artist_id, COUNT(*) c 
  FROM artist ar  
  JOIN album al ON ar.artist_id=al.artist_id  
  GROUP BY ar.artist_id  
  ORDER BY 2 DESC 
  LIMIT 10
)
t JOIN artist ar2 ON ar2.artist_id=t.artist_id
```

I try with your data and it take less than 1 sec. Hope this help

Comment: hi @Itay Moav -Malimovka. You were right, I update the answer, it now take less than 1 sec.